# usage of find_by_sql to delete record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to delete few records from table 'abc' where id is fetched from 'xyz' table

SQL:

```
delete from abc where id in (select ids from xyz where i= 10)
```

this query i want to execute using find_by_sql to avoid multiple hits to database.

It's giving error. Please help me in getting this delete action done in a single hit to DB.

Comment: This is the error:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.all_hashesoccured in Class:

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `find_by_sql` is the method you want.

If you have

```
class Abc < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

(so abc.rb is your model) then I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
Abc.connection.execute('delete from abc where id in (select ids from xyz where i= 10)')
```